# laravel route not active

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

I have route web.php using laravel 5.5, but  can't active if I call this route

### web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'simulasi'], function() {
    Route::get('', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@getSimulasiPremiIndex',
        'as' => 'simulasi.index'
    ]);
```

---

but if I show list this route, its still exist :

### Project>php artisan route:list

[image]

If I access in browser just error :
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `('/')` in your route. and use this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/simulasi'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@getSimulasiPremiIndex', 'simulasi.index'
    ]);
```